# Laravel Routing: How to retrieve a variable from a URL segment wrapped in curly braces?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

If I have the following code:

```
Route::get('/gallery/{gallery?}', function(){
    echo $gallery; // how do I retrieve the gallery variable?
});
```

The reason I want to do this is because the structure of my site is changing and I want to redirect all requests to `/gallery/{something}` to `/galleries/{something}` with something like:

```
Route::get('/gallery/{gallery?}', function(){
    return Redirect::to('/galleries/{gallery}');
});
```

I would prefer to deal with all redirects within my routes file. How can I turn `{gallery}` into `$gallery` so I can do stuff with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the `$gallery` variable in your `function()` to capture it. Note - because you have marked `{gallery?}` as optional - you need to remember to give the function a default setting - i.e. `null`

```
Route::get('/gallery/{gallery?}', function($gallery = null){
    var_dump $gallery;
});
```